# div refreshing for the only first time

Tags: jquery-mobile

i asked this in jquery forum, but maybe it's better here with jquery-mobile tag :

i've a problem i can't go through for 2 days... i'm a newbie in Jquery mobile so maybe you could quickly see the issue :

after an ajax call (to submit a form) i change div content with the ajax response, using $('confirmation').html(newcontent)

but the "new" div has not the cool jqm stylish button and content

then i added $('#confirmation').page(); it was OKAY... but it worked just for once : if i submit the form again, the jqm style dissapears...

i tried everything i found on the net, but still no solution... so i beg your help ;)

thanks by advance to everyone who will have the kindness of having a short look !

here's my example on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ramdam/7cwBX/17/

if you click an Submit ajax button, you'll see a nice BACK button , but if you do it twice, the button "disappears" and only show a link...

Answer (score 0):

Does this: http://jsfiddle.net/7cwBX/20/ helps you?

Comment: ooops, i spoke to soon !

no it's not that, in the example i made a BACK button, but in fact i want to replace the div content with the answer of my ajax call (in that case a button , ok) but after it'll be a lot of buttons, or a list for example

i think the problem is that the jqm style is loaded for elements existing in the html at first (init, dom.ready, whatever) but if i add codes with buttons, or list, the style disappears after the first .page() has been used ONE time

Comment: you can see the problem here : http://jsfiddle.net/7cwBX/29/  for the first run, it's okay with "backnew" button,  but the second time the style dissapears...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you are still using jQuery Mobile alpha 2 version?.To be safe,I would advice to always use the latest jQuery Mobile version-currently RC 1.0 . Update to RC 1.0 and try using `$('#confirmation').trigger('create')` instead of `$('#confirmation').page()`.`page()` is deprecated since beta 2

FYI - I couldnt check out the fix because the domain you used in the example seems to be down.